# why i got error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php

hii i got some error in my source, please help me bro :D i'm newbie in php but this my first project for my personal website :)

```
    $blogku = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY tgl_blog DESC") or die(mysql_error()); // mencari tgl blog dari database blog
$blogku1 = mysql_num_rows($blogku);

if($blogku1 == 0) { // cek database blog ada atau tidak
    echo "<center><h1>tidak ada artikel</h1></center>"; // jika tidak ada artikel akan menampilkan ini
} else { // kalau database artikel ada akan  menampilkan ini
    while($dataku = mysql_fetch_array($blogku)) {
        $postnya = substr($dataku['isi_blog'], 0,150);
        echo '<div class="col-lg-8"><h1>' . $dataku['judul_blog'] . '</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Date and Time <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> : ' . $dataku['tgl_blog'] . ' | Author: ' . $dataku['penulis_blog'] . '</p>
        <hr>
        <img width="250" height="250" class="img-responsive" src="admin/img/' .$dataku['photo_blog'] . '">
        <p class="lead"> ' . $postnya . ' </p>
        <a href="artikel.php?exploded=' . $dataku['id_blog'] . '">Baca Selengkapnya</a>
        </div>
        ';

    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-lg-8"><h1>' . $dataku['judul_blog'] . '</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Date and Time <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> : ' . $dataku['tgl_blog'] . ' | Author: ' . $dataku['penulis_blog'] . '</p>
        <hr>
        <p class="lead"> ' . $postnya . ' </p>
        <a href="artikel.php?exploded=' . $dataku['id_blog'] . '">Baca Selengkapnya</a>
        </div>
        ';
    }

}
```

Comment: you miss **{** after else. add  **} else {** or you you add **else** extra.

Comment: You have extra else in your code

Comment: the `while` - `else`

Comment: You should really look into moving over to mysqli or PDO. mysql_* is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code, error is just due to false else.

```html
<?php 
if($blogku1 == 0) { // cek database blog ada atau tidak
    echo "<center><h1>tidak ada artikel</h1></center>"; // jika tidak ada artikel akan menampilkan ini
} else { // kalau database artikel ada akan  menampilkan ini
    while($dataku = mysql_fetch_array($blogku)) {
        $postnya = substr($dataku['isi_blog'], 0,150);
        echo '<div class="col-lg-8"><h1>' . $dataku['judul_blog'] . '</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Date and Time <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> : ' . $dataku['tgl_blog'] . ' | Author: ' . $dataku['penulis_blog'] . '</p>
        <hr>
        <img width="250" height="250" class="img-responsive" src="admin/img/' .$dataku['photo_blog'] . '">
        <p class="lead"> ' . $postnya . ' </p>
        <a href="artikel.php?exploded=' . $dataku['id_blog'] . '">Baca Selengkapnya</a>
        </div>
        ';

    } 
 
        echo '<div class="col-lg-8"><h1>' . $dataku['judul_blog'] . '</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Date and Time <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> : ' . $dataku['tgl_blog'] . ' | Author: ' . $dataku['penulis_blog'] . '</p>
        <hr>
        <p class="lead"> ' . $postnya . ' </p>
        <a href="artikel.php?exploded=' . $dataku['id_blog'] . '">Baca Selengkapnya</a>
        </div>
        ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code
This is what i think is the problem:
U missed **{** after else

Answer (score 0):

corrected code.

```
$blogku = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY tgl_blog DESC") or die(mysql_error()); // mencari tgl blog dari database blog
$blogku1 = mysql_num_rows($blogku);

if($blogku1 == 0) { // cek database blog ada atau tidak
    echo "<center><h1>tidak ada artikel</h1></center>"; // jika tidak ada artikel akan menampilkan ini
} else { // kalau database artikel ada akan  menampilkan ini
    while($dataku = mysql_fetch_array($blogku)) {
        $postnya = substr($dataku['isi_blog'], 0,150);
        echo '<div class="col-lg-8"><h1>' . $dataku['judul_blog'] . '</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Date and Time <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> : ' . $dataku['tgl_blog'] . ' | Author: ' . $dataku['penulis_blog'] . '</p>
        <hr>
        <img width="250" height="250" class="img-responsive" src="admin/img/' .$dataku['photo_blog'] . '">
        <p class="lead"> ' . $postnya . ' </p>
        <a href="artikel.php?exploded=' . $dataku['id_blog'] . '">Baca Selengkapnya</a>
        </div>
        ';

    } 
        echo '<div class="col-lg-8"><h1>' . $dataku['judul_blog'] . '</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Date and Time <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> : ' . $dataku['tgl_blog'] . ' | Author: ' . $dataku['penulis_blog'] . '</p>
        <hr>
        <p class="lead"> ' . $postnya . ' </p>
        <a href="artikel.php?exploded=' . $dataku['id_blog'] . '">Baca Selengkapnya</a>
        </div>
        ';
}
```